# How to access another user's session in Gorilla Session store?

Tags: go, session, gorilla

I'd like to let moderators to remove a banned user's session, so that he can not post anymore. But what I see in the [gorilla/sessions](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions) documentation is the scenario where you can get session from request:

```
session, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name")
```

However I'm wondering how can I make a request as `Bob` (the moderator) and get the session of another user `Alice` (user to be banned)?

Comment: Be aware that this project is no longer maintained. You may want to look for alternatives.

Comment: I know that. What is the most viable alternative to Gorilla session?